# Get tweets of a topic Twitter API

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I have a certain Twitter topic (and its id) that I want to pull the recent tweets of ..

I know the topic of a certain tweet is stored in its “context_annotations” attribute.

Is there a way in Twitter API to pull tweets of a certain topic, similar to how we pull tweets of certain keywords or hashtags?

I have looked in the search query and twitter api v2 and seem to have found nothing in that matter ..

https://github.com/igorbrigadir/twitter-advanced-search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use:

```
https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?query=context%3A<domain_id>.<entity_id>
```

The Twitter API allows for searching by a domain ID / entity ID pair using the `context:` operator. (Searching using only a domain ID is not supported.) This functionality is described further [in this documentation page](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/integrate/build-a-query) under the section "Find Tweets that relate to a specific Tweet annotation".

For example, if you wanted to find tweets related to domain `66` (Interests and Hobbies) and entity ID `852262932607926273` (Cats), you'd use:

```
https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?query=context%3A66.852262932607926273
```

Comment: Yes that’s it .. Thank you!! There was no mention of this in advanced twitter search index but I completely forgot to check The API documentation itself ..